# why can we not replace $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1}/a_{n}|>1 $ by $ \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1}/a_{n}| >1 $?

Tags: complex-analysis

An example in my textbook: 
let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $ be convergent and $ a_n := b_{(n+1)/2} $for n in 2 (Natural numbers) -1 and $ a_n:= 2b_{n/2} $ for $n$ in $2$ (Natural numbers). 
Then, 
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n= b_1+2b_1 +b_2+2b_2+b_3 +2b_3+...$ converges but $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1}/a_{n}| \geq 2 $

I do not understand why $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $ converges and how the lim sup is greater than or equal to 2 ?

Comment: How does the body of this question relate to the title of the question? If I had to guess, I'd guess that your book is offering an example to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1}/a_{n}| >1$ is not a strong enough condition to prevent convergence; but why should we have to guess? I suggest either to add something at the beginning of the question explaining what the rest of the question has to do with the title, or change the title to something like "How does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge and how is $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|\geq2$?"

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_n b_n<\infty$ then $\sum_n a_n\leq 3\sum_n b_n<\infty$ (by just what you wrote expanding $\sum_n a_n$). The point is that each $b_n$ repeats only twice (at most) in expanding $\sum_n a_n$ and therefore $\sum_n a_n<\infty$.

Look at the sequence $c_n=|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ then there are infinitely many $n$ such that $c_n=2$ (again look at your $a_n$'s) so $\limsup_n c_n\geq2$.